# How to give background color to button in lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I am not able to give background color to buttons below.please help
[image]

Comment: what problem you are facing because lightning support css. use background -color css for this.

Comment: Ajay.... try like this.. http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_basic

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed the quotes in the `ui:inputText` field. Also, there's spelling mistake in the `ui:inputText`

**Component:**

```
<ui:inputText label="enter name"/> 
<div>  
    <ui:button label="PROGRAMS" class="customButton" /> 
    <ui:button label="Learning" class="customButton" /> 
    <ui:button label="Training" class="customButton" /> 
    <ui:button label="Contacts" class="customButton" /> 
    <ui:button label="SUPPORT" class="customButton" /> 
</div>
```

**Style:**

```
.THIS .customButton{
   background-color: #2574a9;
   color: #fff; 
}
```

**Result:**
[image: Result]

You may modify the styling as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In Your case:

a) If ui:button contains **NO** class

.THIS .uiButton{
     background-color:blue;
   }

b) If ui:button **contains** class

.THIS .uiButton.classname{
     background-color:blue;
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui:button label="PROGRAMS" class="customButton" />
```

.THIS .customButton{
   background-color: #2574a9 **!important;**
   color: #fff; 
}